# React navigation in react-native v0.60 is broken

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

After following https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html

(not using expo)

I followed the guide and disabled auto-linking by creating react-native.config.js file

But when I run react-native run-android

```
 error: package com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react does not exist

 error: cannot find symbol
         return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);
```

After this error tried adding below line in

```
**project/android/app/build.gradle**

 implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
```

And cleaned gradle build and react-native run-android reset-cache

But now it says following error

```
error: package androidx.core.util does not exist
import androidx.core.util.Pools;

Upgrade android v4 support library to androidx
```

Because react-navigation-handler does not use androidX where as react-native v0.60 is completely migrated to AndroidX which says breaking change.

React navigation is dead for now...

If anyone can make this work please provide me the GitHub repo by uploading the working code with **createStackNavigator**

Required

React-native 0.60 latest
React-navigation v3

---

> Note: createStackNavigator uses platform conventions by default

---

Comment: RN 0.60 is full of issues, wasted a lot of time solving these build issues. I simply downgraded to 0.59.9 version.

Comment: Hi all, 
Jetifier is not what I am looking for this question as I want to use Android X.
But Jetifier is a workaround for using Android Library.
I have already tried it https://github.com/edgeineer/React_Native0.60-React_Native_Navigation3.11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated to the following version

```
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
"react-navigation": "^3.11.1"
```

Its working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I am already migrated to 0.60 and I manually migrated any packages that I use to androidx, here https://github.com/DNA-h/react-native-gesture-handler is my version of recat-native-gesture-handler which is androidx compatible. You may also try @HungrySoul solution too, but sooner or later people will migrate to androidx

Answer (score 0):

Yep react-native-gesture-handler needs to migrate to androidX

Try :

```
npm install --save-dev jetifier
npx jetify
```

https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/678#issuecomment-509928220

Comment: Tried  Jetifier does not work with latest apps created with RN-0.60 React-native init newproject